# How can I deduce the outer type of an inner type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have many classes exposing an inner type named `Binding`. For instance, one of them could be:

```
struct Message
{
    struct Binding
    {
    };
};
```

I invoke a function `apply` like this:

```
apply< Message >([](Message::Binding& x)
{
    // setup binding fields
});
```

for I wrote

```
template <class TMessage, class TBindingExpression>
void apply(const TBindingExpression& expr)
{
    typedef typename TMessage::Binding BindingType;

    BindingType binding;
    expr(binding);

    apply(MessageUtil::typeId< TMessage >(), binding);
}
```

Since `Message` is a bit redundant in the way I invoke `apply`, I would like to make the compiler deduce `Message` so I can write

```
apply([](Message::Binding x)
{
    //...
});
```

So far, I am stuck here:

```
template <class TBindingExpression>
void apply(const TBindingExpression& expr)
{
    // I get the type of the argument which is Message::Binding in this example
    typedef typename std::tuple_element
    <
        0,
        FunctionTraits< TBindingExpression >::ArgumentTypes
    >
    ::type BindingType;

    // so I can invoke my expression
    BindingType binding;
    expr(binding);

    // But now I need the type of the outer class, i.e. Message
    typedef typename MessageTypeFromBinding< BindingType >::Type MessageType;

    apply(MessageUtil::typeId< MessageType >(), binding);
}
```

Is there a way to write/achieve `MessageTypeFromBinding`?

Obviously, that's pure curiosity and cosmetic concerns.

Comment: IIRC it's not possible (similarly to getting the namespace where a type has been declared). You can however provide a typedef in `Binding`. Also, function objects are conventionally passed by value; it is dangerous to rely on function traits to get the *single* parameter type of the first parameter of `operator()` or similar, consider overloaded `operator()` or even C++1y's polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: @dyp: why using my `FunctionTraits` to get a single argument's type is dangerous?

Comment: How is a second type template argument redundant? How is the compiler supposed to know what the type `BindingType` is supposed to be, and hence what overload to call when calling `TBindingExpression`?

Comment: @misterwhy because it only works for a small subset of callable entities.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: you are absolutely right in this context.

Comment: In c++14 the call `apply< Message >([](auto& x) { // setup binding fields });` which eliminates the redundancy.

Comment: @Yakk: ah ah! Thanks anyway, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

```
template<class T>struct inner_class_of{using outer_class=T;}; 

struct Message {
  struct Binding:inner_class_of<Message> {
  };
};

template<class T>
inner_class_of<T> get_outer_helper(inner_class_of<T>const&);

template<class T>
using outer_class_of_t = typename decltype(get_outer_helper(std::declval<T>()))::outer_class;
```

now `outer_class_of_t<Message::Binding>` is `Message`.

I made it a bit industrial strength, as it works even if `Binding` hides `outer_class`.

You can drop helper and rewrite `outer_class_of_t=typename T::outer_class` if you prefer.