# Could this templated syntax be improved?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, methods

I have this template method:

```
template <class SomeLhs, class SomeRhs, 
          ResultType (SomeLhs::*callback)(SomeRhs&)>
void Add() {
  struct Local {
    static ResultType Trampoline(BaseLhs& lhs, BaseRhs& rhs) {
      return (static_cast<SomeLhs&>(lhs).*callback)(static_cast<SomeRhs&>(rhs));
    }
  };
  _back_end.template Add<SomeLhs,SomeRhs>(&Local::Trampoline);
}
```

Currently I'm calling it like this:

```
tracker.Add<Quad, Multi, &Quad::track>();
tracker.Add<Quad, Singl, &Quad::track>();
tracker.Add<Sext, Multi, &Sext::track>();
...
```

It is working fine, but I don't like to have to repeat two times the name of class `SomeLhs`. Is there a way to avoid that?

For people who may have recognized it: yes, this is related to the BasicFastDispatcher of Alexandrescu, in particular I'm writing a front end to operate with member functions.

Comment: It's not necessarily always the "track" function, I assume!? How are you using callback inside Add?

Comment: @WernerHenze In principle it could be another function, I would like to keep this possibility. The Add() is almost the same as the Alexandrescu's one (page 244 of Modern C++ Design) with just some weird syntax to manipulate member function (I added it in the question).

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206337/how-can-i-deduce-the-outer-type-of-an-inner-type-in-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it can't be improved particularly, which is unfortunate as I'd love to find a way to do this.

Template type deduction is only possible for function template arguments and you need to pass in the non-type member function pointer at compile time in order for it to be treated as a name rather than a varying quantity.  Which means having to specify all the args.

i.e. you can do this:

```
template <class SomeLhs, class SomeRhs>
void Add(ResultType (SomeLhs::*callback)(SomeRhs&)) {
  ...
}
// nice syntax:
tracker.Add(&Sext::track);
// But ugly for overloaded functions, a cast is needed.
// p.s. not sure this is exactly the right syntax without compiling it.
tracker.Add((ResultType (Quad::*)(Multi&) &Quad::track);
```

But then you have an actual pointer that cannot subsequently be used as a template parameter.

The only thing I think you could do is to use a macro, though it is arguable if it really improves syntax here.  I'd say it probably adds an unnecessary level of obfuscation.

e.g.

```
#define TMFN_ARGS(C, M, P1) C, P1, &C::M
tracker.Add<TMFN_ARGS(Quad, track, Multi)>();
```

EDIT:

However, if the name of the function is Always 'track', you could do something along the following lines:

```
template <typename C, typename P1>
void AddTrack() {
   Add<C, P1, &C::track>();
}
tracker.AddTrack<Quad, Multi>();
```

Comment: +1 both for the macro solution (I tend to forget that they exist!) and for the `AddTrack()`: I'm not planning to have a bunch of different functions, so I can easily go with that.

Comment: You still always have the more verbose 'Add' function available for any other cases.