# C++ partial type inference for template parameter - Is it possible?

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-inference

I have a situation where I have nested structs like this:

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {};
};
```

And I have some template code that needs to know the OUTER type (in this case, 'A').
So I'm trying to write a template function that can infer the outer type, and it looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void func(typename T::B item)
{}

int main()
{
    A::B item;
    func(item);   // Error here because "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'"
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile, and the reason is given in the comment above.

---

Now, I could of course simplify the template to something like this, but as you can see below it does not satisfy my requirements of knowing the "outer" type, which is A.

```
template<typename T>
void func(typename T item)
{
    // Oops, I now have the complete type of A::B but I have a
    // specialized function that needs the A without the B as the type parameter
    someOtherFunc<???>(...);   // The ??? needs to be type A only, without the B
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206337/how-can-i-deduce-the-outer-type-of-an-inner-type-in-c.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `typedef A outerType;` to your class B.
Then the implementation of func might be:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
struct B {
    typedef A outerType;
};
};

template <class T>
void func( T f)
{
    typedef typename T::outerType outerType;
    outerType a;
    someotherfunc(a);
}   

int main ()
{
    A::B item;
    func(item);

    return 0;
}
```

Then of course every inner class you have should name its outer Type outerType to make func work out the outer Type.