# Deduce outer type from inner type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, type-deduction

Given `struct outer { struct inner { }; }`, I want to deduce the outer type from a parameter having the inner type:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) { ... }

f(outer::inner p)
{
    // deduce typename 'outer' here
}
```

Assume that all `outer` of interest have an inner named `inner`.

Comment: This solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24206337/1774667 ?

Comment: @Yakk, I don't own the parameter types; I can't instrument them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As alternative, you may create a traits that you feed manually:

```
template <typename T> struct outer_type;

template <> struct outer_type<outer::inner> { using type = outer; };
// ... other specialization for each outer::inner types
```

And then:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    using outer = typename outer_type<T>::type;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It may be possible to do this via an enumeration of outer type.  Create a type with `()` overloaded on `tag<outer::inner>` to return `tag<outer>` and `...` to `tag<void>` or somesuch.  Then `result_of_t<foo(tag<T>)>` to get `tag<outer>` from `T=outer::inner`, and extract type within tag.

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry, template argument deduction will not be able to do this for you.

You should include in `inner` a typedef to the `outer` type instead.

```
struct outer {
    struct inner {
        using OuterType = outer;
    };
};

template <typename inner>
void f(inner x) {
    typedef typename inner::OuterType outer;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I understand how this works, but I don't have access to this param in order to instrument it like this.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod I think you should accept the other answer then